# TYPO3: tx-news - localize tag, render tags multilingual, missing step

Tags: overriding, typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

I use tx-news in a multilingual site and need to have the tags localized, (scripted from a custom extension):

**1) first step**: add the fields to the table:

*ext_tables.sql* :

```
#
# Extend table structure of table 'tx_news_domain_model_tag'
#
CREATE TABLE tx_news_domain_model_tag (
    sys_language_uid int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    l10n_parent int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    l10n_diffsource mediumblob
);
```

**2) second step**: TCA override tag  **(now fully working, added 'allLanguages' selection as suggested by ralph)**

*Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tx_news_domain_model_tag.php*

```
<?php
defined('TYPO3_MODE') or die();

/**
 * Add multilingual to tx_news_domain_model_tag
 */

$temporaryColumns = [
    'sys_language_uid' => [
        'exclude' => 1,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.language',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
            'special' => 'languages',
            'items' => [
                [
                    'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.allLanguages',
                    -1,
                    'flags-multiple'
                ],
            ],
            'default' => 0,
        ],
    ],
    'l10n_parent' => [
        'displayCond' => 'FIELD:sys_language_uid:>:0',
        'exclude' => 1,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.l18n_parent',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
            'items' => [
                   ['', 0],
            ],
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_tag',
            'foreign_table_where' => 'AND tx_news_domain_model_tag.pid=###CURRENT_PID### AND tx_news_domain_model_tag.sys_language_uid IN (-1,0)',
        ],
    ],
    'l10n_diffsource' => [
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'passthrough',
        ],
    ],
];

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns(
        'tx_news_domain_model_tag',
        $temporaryColumns
);
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addFieldsToPalette(
        'tx_news_domain_model_tag',
        'paletteCore',
        'sys_language_uid, l10n_parent, l10n_diffsource',
        'before:hidden'
);
/* ADDED MISSING SYNTAX AFTER PAUL'S ANSWER */
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_news_domain_model_tag']['ctrl']['languageField'] = 'sys_language_uid';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_news_domain_model_tag']['ctrl']['transOrigPointerField'] = 'l10n_parent';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_news_domain_model_tag']['ctrl']['transOrigDiffSourceField'] = 'l10n_diffsource';
```

**3) third step**: TCA override news to limit tags to the language

*Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tx_news_domain_model_news.php*

```
/**
 * Add This to the original **`tags`** column
 */

...

'foreign_table_where' => ' AND tx_news_domain_model_tag.sys_language_uid IN (-1, 0) ORDER BY tx_news_domain_model_tag.title',

...
```

**4) fourth step**: add the localization to the TCA of tx_news_domain_model_tag **(added paul's answer to step 2, this is NOT missing anymore)**

the following should be added **but I don't know how ...** (from a custom extension, I obviously can add it directly within 'news')

```
'ctrl' => [
    'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
    'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
    'transOrigDiffSourceField' => 'l10n_diffsource'
    ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try just to override it in the TCA array inside your Overrides/tx_news_domain_model_tag.php like this?

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_news_domain_model_tag']['ctrl']['languageField'] = 'sys_language_uid';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_news_domain_model_tag']['ctrl']['transOrigPointerField'] = 'l10n_parent';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_news_domain_model_tag']['ctrl']['transOrigDiffSourceField'] = 'l10n_diffsource';
```

Comment: thank you, mind that the working syntax uses **`=`** and not **`=>`**

Comment: Fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

... just one small addition. To get the option "All" in the language selector you have to change the array sys_language_uid in Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tx_news_domain_model_tag.php like this
...

```
'sys_language_uid' => [
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.language',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
        'special' => 'languages',
        'items' => [
            [
                'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.allLanguages',
                -1,
                'flags-multiple'
            ],
        ],
        'default' => 0,
    ],
],
```

...